# How to Do Trigonometric Range of Floats in Python?

Tags: python, math

Matlab

```
x = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
y = sin(x);
plot(y)
```

I think `range()` cannot work here because it only accepts end arguments as integers but I need floats (`0.0; 2*pi`). 
Pseudocode in Python 2.7.11+

```
import math
x = pseudoRange(0.0, 2*math.pi, math.pi/100);
```

Taking `ceil()` is not practical for integers.

---

How can you have the trigonometric range of floats in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
>>> np.arange(0, 2*math.pi, math.pi/100)
array([ 0.        ,  0.03141593,  0.06283185,  0.09424778,  0.12566371,
        # ... 190 more ...
        6.12610567,  6.1575216 ,  6.18893753,  6.22035345,  6.25176938])
```

You might also be interested in [`numpy.linspace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace):

```
>>> np.linspace(0, 2*math.pi, 200)
array([ 0.        ,  0.0315738 ,  0.06314759,  0.09472139,  0.12629518,
        # ... 190 more ...
        6.15689013,  6.18846392,  6.22003772,  6.25161151,  6.28318531])
```

Using `np.arange`, the third parameter is the `step`, while with `np.linspace` it's the total number of evenly-spaced values in the interval. Also note that `linspace` will include the `2*pi`, while `arange` does not, but stop at the last multiple of `step` smaller than that.

You can then plot those with `matplotlib.pyplot`. For `sin`, you can just use `np.sin` which will apply the sine function to each element of the input array. For other functions, use a list comprehension.

```
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot
>>> x = np.arange(0, 2*math.pi, math.pi/100)
>>> y = np.sin(x) # using np.sin
>>> y = [math.sin(r) for r in x] # using list comprehension
>>> pyplot.plot(x, y)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xb3c3210c>]
>>>pyplot.show()
```

Comment: after edit you do show that `np.sin(x)` does apply `sin` to each element of the array but you may consider mentioning this more explicitly since the OP is coming from matlab where that is common behaviour.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Right, added. PS.: Thanks for the fix. Turns out that meant something entirely different in English...

Answer (score 5):

Use a generator expression:

```
(math.pi/100*k for k in range(200))
```

If you want the result as a list use:

```
[math.pi/100*k for k in range(200)]
```

You can also use the list-comprehension approach to get the corresponding y-values:

```
x = [math.pi/100*k for k in range(200)]
y = [math.sin(p) for p in x]
```

Then the pair of lists `x,y` can be plotted using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/)

Note that in the above, the points will range from `0.0` to `1.99*math.pi`. If you wanted the final point to be `2*pi` itself, you would need to replace `range(200)` by `range(201)`.

Comment: Since he apparently wants to plot in something like Matlab, namely matplotlib, he seems to want a list. Two lists, probably, one for the x-values (which is what you show) and another for the y-values. You may want to show the list of y-values, using the `sin()` function.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Good suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have `matplotlib` already installed or that you can install it on your system, a sort of `matlab` clone is available under the `pylab` namespace,

```
import pylab as pl

x = pl.linspace(0, 2*pl.pi,201) #  x is an array
y = pl.sin(x)                   #  y is computed with an array expression
pl.plot(x, y, "ro-", label="Sine(t)")
pl.legend(loc='best')
pl.xlabel('$\\omega_o t$')
pl.show()
```

You can also import directly all `pylab`'s namespace

```
from pylab import *

x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 201)
y = sin(x)
...
```

but this is not recommended, because you have now almost 1000 new, not qualified names in your namespace...

Coming to your question strictly, `x = 0:pi/100:2*pi;` maps to a different syntax, `x = pl.linspace(0, 2*pl.pi,201)`, where you don't specify the increment but the number of points (as you have noted, due to fence effect you have to specify `201` to have the desired result).